# How do I trigger autocomplete without a tab key?

Tags: bash, ssh, keyboard, autocomplete

I'm ssh-ing to my machine using my iPhone with an app called ServerAuditior. It doesn't have tab key. See screenshot.

How do I trigger autocomplete without the tab key? I don't want to type a lot of characters for cd-ing.

I have arrow keys in this app. I can swipe down left right to use arrow keys. It would be amazing if I can bind it to forward arrow key when blinker in at end of my command

[image]

Comment: According to the [current description of ServerAuditor](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/server-auditor-ssh-client/id549039908?mt=8), double-tapping sends the tab character.

Comment: Related: [Trigger programmatically autocomplete event for shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42085071/55075)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can bind the completion command to any key sequence.  Pick something that's easy to type but unlikely to appear in a normal command, like say capital A.  Put `bind "A":complete` in `~/.bashrc`, and new bash instances will use capital A as well as <kbd>TAB</kbd> to invoke completion.

Comment: You don't, at least not to bash.  Normally I would tell you to type Control-q A or Control-v A to get an A in this case but you don't seem to have a control key either.  Pick Z or one of the easy symbols if A looks like something you can't live without.

Comment: Works for me. btw for the record my question was "how do I type A" which I deleted  right before you answer it.

Comment: For some reason I didn't see the Ctrl button overlaying the text, so you could use that, I guess.

Comment: If you need an `A` in a command, as long as it is either a path/filename parameter or in the command itself, you can use `?` then hit that `A` to autocomplete. Or you can put a file in some strategic location that you can autocomplete to, to get the A. Not something you'd want to do very often, but for the occasional time when you need whatever you bind to autocomplete to not autocomplete, it should work.

Answer (score 30):

Typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> sends the same character as <kbd>Tab</kbd> would.  This should work without rebinding any keys.

Answer (score 7):

in emacs mode, hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> seems to have the same effect as <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: I have to hit `ESC` 6 times before it autocompletes, then it does it every two `ESC` after that. `gnome-terminal` in GNU `screen`

Answer (score 4):

According to the [ServerAuditor](http://www.serverauditor.com/) page, "Tab activated by a double touch gesture".

Other iOS ssh clients that I've seen have a way of triggering a tab.